# border z-index problem

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/59MWq/1/

I am trying to partially hide the top border of the .dropdown by applying the bottom border of the navigation with a white colour.  For some reason, it is not working.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your jQuery code add this

```
 $(".navigation").css("position","relative");
 $(".navigation").css("z-index","1");
```

you have to bring the `.navigation` bar above the popup using `z-index`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/59MWq/9/

Also try to use a  map for [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), like this:

```
 $(".navigation").css({"border-left":"1px black solid",
                              "padding-left":"9px",
                              "border-top":"1px black solid",
                              "padding-top":"4px",
                              "border-right":"1px black solid",
                              "padding-right":"9px",
                              "background-color":"white",
                              "padding-bottom":"4px",
                              "border-bottom":"1px white solid",
                              "position":"relative",
                              "z-index":"1"});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/59MWq/10/

Comment: Or better would be to use a class with `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:
[this effort](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/59MWq/8/)